# How do I configure webpack to support virtual paths in some hosts?

Tags: asp.net-core, webpack-4

I'm buiding an application using ASP.NET Core for the backend and running a React application for the client-side. I've set up webpack to transpile SASS to CSS, TypeScript to JavaScript, and I use the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to add these bundles to the `_Layout.cshtml` file. The bundles are published to `wwwroot/dist/`

This all works great with my local development hosting. The challenge comes when I try to run the application within a virtual directory (a requirement of some of my deployments). ASP.NET will resolve virtual paths to full paths based on the hosting information (e.g. `~\resource` resolves to `\virtual-directory\resource`), but the webpack resources are compiled to fixed paths.

I've tried setting the `publicPath` property to generate virtual paths:

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/dist'),
    publicPath: '~/dist/'
}
```

Whilst this works great for the bundles referenced by my `_Layout.cshtml` file, inserting `href` values prefixed with the virtual path identifier that ASP.NET will resolve, it doesn't work when any of the bundles reference other files, such as images. These references don't get resolved by ASP.NET and the browser tries to load a resource at `https://host/~/dist/images/cat.png`.

What I would like is for all resources to be resolved relative to the application root, rather than the host root.

Answer (score 1):

The `~/` path construction is not standard. Razor understands that to mean relative to document root and replaces it with a host-relative path that works. If what you're doing isn't being processed by Razor, however, then you cannot use that.

The best you can do is self-relative paths (`path/to/file`, i.e. no preceding `/`) or host-relative paths (`/path/to/file`, i.e. with a preceding `/`). In the former case, the path will be interpreted from the path of the file in context. For example, if the path is in a JS file, then it will be relative to wherever that JS file is located. In the latter case, it will be relative to the host, i.e. the full path from the host, including any virtual directories.

There's nothing else you have to work with, because there's no concept of an application root in a file system utility like webpack. That concept only exists within the context of a running application.

Comment: Webpack's asset resolution wants to use host-relative paths and assumes you always know that path at build-time. I can't see a way to make it use self-relative paths. Is there any solution?

Comment: As I said, no. The virtual directories you're talking about only exist in the context of the running application in your web server (IIS, for example). Outside of that, there's no way to know or tell what the path should be.